# Play JSON variable in scala.html contains quotes when passing to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, playframework

The idea is that I want to use the json from a route (scala.html) then draw it with D3.
Unfortunately, when the string is handed to javascript, it contains a quotes in the original JSON.

```
@(userId: Int, advertiserId: Int, json: String)
@main {
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="split">
            <thead></thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
        </table>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        @{
            // This is the correct json 
            println(json)
        }
        // OK malformed JSON    
        console.log(@json);
        </script>
    </body>
}
```

This is from Javascript console
`console.log([{&quot;id&quot;:1,&quot;campaignId&quot;:1}];`
Am I missing something here?

Comment: @Mikesname: Many thanks. That was deadly simple